# Searching all files in folder for strings

Tags: php, linux

I am looking for the fastest approach for searching for some string into some folder structure. I know that I can get all content from the file with file_get_contents, but I am not sure if is fast. Maybe there is already some solution that works fast. I was thinking about using scandir to get all files and file_get_contents to read it's content and strpos to check if the string exist.

Do you think there is some better way od doing this?

Or maybe trying to use php exec with grep?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/skfaisal93/AnyWhereInFiles

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your two options are [DirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) or [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

```
$string = 'something';

$dir = new DirectoryIterator('some_dir');
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    $content = file_get_contents($file->getPathname());
    if (strpos($content, $string) !== false) {
        // Bingo
    }
}

$dir = 'some_dir';
foreach (glob("$dir/*") as $file) {
    $content = file_get_contents("$dir/$file");
    if (strpos($content, $string) !== false) {
        // Bingo
    }
}
```

In terms of performance, you can always [compute the real-time speed of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1202746/427992) or find out [memory usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) quite easily. For larger files, you might want to use [an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059073/427992) to `file_get_contents`.

Comment: your solutions checks filenames and I need to check file content. is there a big difference to the code?

Answer (score 3):

use directory iterator and foreach:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: is that faster than grep and file_get_contents?