# How to iterate and search the content of files in public/storage/?

Tags: laravel

I have a set of text files inside `public/storage/` and I need to search their content, I tried to tailor this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15041680/6811102) to work in Laravel but with no success

```
public function search($query)
{
    $dir = new \DirectoryIterator(public_path('public'));

    foreach ($dir as $file) {
        return $file;
        $content = file_get_contents(public_path($file));
        if (strpos($content, $query) !== false) {
            return 'yes';
        } else {
            return 'no';
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the problem with the code is that I don't know how Laravel accesses paths.

---

File structure in Laravel:

```
project
│
└───public
    │
    └───storage
        │ 
        │ file1.txt
        │ file2.txt
        │ ...
        └───
```

Comment: Do you have other files in your storage directory?  Seems like a bad idea to try to read every single file.

Comment: Can you include your file structure?

Comment: @Devon yes there are other files, but my plan is to put the text files inside a dedicated directory

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I added the file structure of Laravel `public/storage`

Answer (score 3):

This should work the way you intent to check the contents of each file:

```
$dir = new \DirectoryIterator(public_path('storage'));

foreach ($dir as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        $content = file_get_contents($file->getRealPath());

        if (str_contains($content, $query)) {
            return 'yes';
        }
    }
}

return 'no';
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to return strings.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova, this is added just for testing, the OP probably needs the full file contents or true/false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the path to `public/storage`, you need to call `public_path('storage')`.

Also you could use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob), but that depends on your folder/file structure.

Example:

```
$files = glob(public_path('/storage') . '/*.txt');
```

This will return an array of all files that have `.txt` extension in `public/storage/`.

If those files are in folders inside `public/storage` you need to recursively get all those files.