# PHP Finding a string from a file in a controller, inside a model

Tags: php, string, model, controller, find

I loading a file from a controller and trying to find a string from that file inside a model.

The function in the controller i have written has:

```
<?php
    public function file() {
        $filename = "C:/Users/Declan/Desktop/foo.txt";
    }
?>
```

And In the model I would have:

```
<?php
    function find{
        if( exec('grep '.escapeshellarg($_GET['bar']).'$filename')) {
            echo "string found";
        }
    }
?>
```

I am using [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059026/php-check-if-file-contains-a-string) as reference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do the `find()` function is in the same class than you're `file()` function

Comment: You are missing the parenthesis at the end of find, it should be `find()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the exec() method who is use to run an external program.
You are on windows apparently, grep is only for unix system (Linux ...).

```
<?php
    function find($filePath, $stringToLookFor){
       $handle = fopen($filePath, 'r');

        $stringFound = false; // Init false
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) { // Loop through each file line
            if (strpos($buffer, $stringToLookFor) !== false) { // Check if in $buffer
                $stringFound = true; // String found
            }      
        }
        fclose($handle);
        return $stringFound;
    }
?>
```