# fwrite if string doesn't exist in file

Tags: php

I am currently working an auto-content-generator script's sitemap. I got to know that google accept sitemap in simple text file that contains one URL per line.

so I created a file named `1.txt` and wrote a script to add current page URL to `1.txt` when a user visits.

`test.php` is:

```
$file = 'assets/sitemap/1.txt';
$url = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]."\n";
$file = fopen($file, 'a');
fwrite($file, $url);
fclose( $file );
```

This script writes the page URLto `1.txt` every time someone hits the page. But the problem is, it creates too much duplicate links. So I want to add a filter to not add a string (URL in this case) if it already exists.

After surfing a while, I got a solution here (second snippet) that is resource friendly: [PHP check if file contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059026/php-check-if-file-contains-a-string)

I made the following modification but it is not working (not adding anything at all):

```
$file = 'assets/sitemap/1.txt';
$url = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]."\n";
if(exec('grep '.escapeshellarg($url).' assets/sitemap/1.txt')) {}
else{
    $file = fopen($file, 'a');
    fwrite($file, $url);
    fclose( $file );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hopefully easier to understand:

```
$file = 'assets/sitemap/1.txt';
$url  = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]."\n";

$text = file_get_contents($file);

if(strpos($text, $url) === false) {
    file_put_contents($file, $url, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

- Read the file contents into a string `$text` using `file_get_contents()`
- Check if `$url` is in the string `$text` using `strpos()`
- If `$url` is not in the string `$text`, append the `$url` to the file using `file_put_contents()`

To count the total lines, you can start using `file()` to load the file lines into an array.  Then check if the `$url` is in the array using `in_array()`:

```
$lines = file($file);
$count = count($lines); // count the lines

if(!in_array($url, $text)) {
    file_put_contents($file, $url, FILE_APPEND);
    $count++; // if added, add 1 to count
}
```

Comment: does it also add link to 1.txt beside checking string's existence?

Comment: append = write may be?

Comment: is there any way to count total line? I cant do it with fopen but it would be great if it be done with same `file_get_contents()`. dont wanna load the file again.

Comment: Edited to use an array.