# how can i ban specific numbers from a .txt file?

Tags: php

I made a text file named `ben.txt` and there are some numbers line by line, for example `123456` so i want, whenever someone type `!check 123456` so they should get message like `Number Banned`
I Made a code But it doesn't working

My Code

```
$been = file_get_contents(ben.txt);
$isbanned = false;
foreach ($been as $bb) {
  if(strpos($message, "!sa $bb") ===0) $isbanned = true;
 sendMessage($chatId, "<b>Number Banned!</b>");
return;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP check if file contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059026/php-check-if-file-contains-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the contents of the file into a regular expression that matches any of the strings.

```
$ex_cont = file("ben.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$isbanned = false;
$regex = '/^!sa (' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $ex_cont)) . ')/';
if (preg_match($regex, $message)) {
    $isbanned = true;
    sendMessage($chatId, "<b>Number Banned!</b>");
}
```